# How to declare a Camel Producer bean with Spring

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I am new to spring and Camel, and having a hard time understanding exactly what this part of the Camel bean integration requires:

"If a bean is defined in Spring XML or scanned using the Spring component scanning mechanism and a  is used or a CamelBeanPostProcessor then we process a number of Camel annotations"

I have a Camel context declared in a spring context file and deployed as an OSGI bundle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
              http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
            <from uri="timer://myTimer?fixedRate=true&amp;period=2000"/>
            <to uri="log:ExampleRouter"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>

</beans>
```

In a separate bundle I have existing java code that needs to produce content, and I have inserted an @Producer field annotation. In that second bundle I have declared a Spring bean... however the POJO exists already and I don't expect/want Spring to actually instantiate it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
              http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <bean id="CrudEditManager" class="com.acme.editmgr.internal.EditManagerServiceImpl"/>
</beans>
```

As it stands the @Producer annotation is not processed, and I am not too sure how I should proceed to point the CamelBeanPostProcessor at the existing instance of my POJO?
The Camel route starts fine, and for the second bundle I see this in the logs:

```
defining beans [CrudEditManager]; root of factory hierarchy
```

... so the configuration files are being loaded, but there is some missing wiring that I can't figure out.

Thanks!

========== Edit ============
Looking into this a bit further, and short of using Aspect Weaver I clearly will need to use a spring managed bean for those annotations to work. It also seems like in an OSGI context I should get the bean from the Spring application context started by my Camel bundle.
So I have replaced the @Produce annotation in my POJO with this java code:

```
    Dictionary<String,String> filter = new Hashtable<>();
filter.put("org.springframework.context.service.name",
                   <name of my camel bundle");
tracker = ServiceHelper.create(context, ApplicationContext.class, filter);
        producer = tracker.getService().getBean(CrudEditProducer.class);
```

I wonder if there is a simpler way to bridge into the spring managed bean space from a POJO?